# Object reference not set to an instance of an object Null Reference Exception was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I keep getting an error when I am trying to create a new account from a function that checks if a username is already taken in a database. Here is my code.

```
Public Class CreatePatientAccountPage1

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        MainScreen.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        If CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1.CheckUsername(UsernameTextBox2.Text) = Nothing Then
            CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1.CreateAccount(UsernameTextBox2.Text, PasswordTextBox2.Text)
            MsgBox("Account Created")
        Else
            MsgBox("Username is taken")
        End If

        CreatePatientAccountPage2.Show()
        Return
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: On which line is the exception occuring? Also please tag your question with the relevant Visual Basic tag (e.g. VB6, VB.net)

Comment: The exception is on If CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1.CheckUsername(UsernameTextBox2.Text) = Nothing Then

Comment: Then put a breakpoint on that line of code and check which of the two things are null.

Comment: Where would I be placing the Me keyword?

Like this?
Me.CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1.CheckUsername(UsernameTextBox2.Text) = Nothing Then

Comment: Try using `Is Nothing` instead of `= Nothing`.  Also check the return type of CheckUserName.

Comment: Try: "If IsNothing(CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1.CheckUsername(UsernameTextBox2.Text)) = True Then". What is the return type of CheckUsername?

Answer (score 0):

Here I could see that you haven't created any objects for those classes you have called.

use the following lines instead of your code,

```
 dim obj1 as new CreatePatientaccountTableAdapter1
 dim obj2 as new CreatePatientAccountPage2
 If obj1.CheckUsername(UsernameTextBox2.Text) = Nothing Then
        obj2.CreateAccount(UsernameTextBox2.Text, PasswordTextBox2.Text)
        MsgBox("Account Created")
    Else
        MsgBox("Username is taken")
    End If

    obj2.Show()
```